# Using viewmodel to pass different views to partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a view that renders 2 partial views.  One partial is a list of people.  The other partial is a modal edit form to edit a single person.   I have a viewmodel that contains a person model and a list of person model.  I pass the viewmodel to the view and specify the specific models for the partials.  I get an error saying the view requires the PersonModel instead of the PersonViewModel. However, the view needs the viewmodel or it wont work.

The Viewmodel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<Person> PeopleList { get; set; }
}
```

The view (Index):

```
@model App.Models.ViewModels.PersonViewModel
<h1>Manage People</h1>

@Html.Partial("_personEditForm", Model.Person)
@Html.Partial("_PersonGrid", Model.PersonList)
```

The person edit partial calls the Person model:

```
@model App.Models.Person
```

and the grid partial calls the same model as a list:

```
@model List<App.Models.Person>
```

This works fine if the page has only one partial, but this is the first time I have tried it with 2 and it fails. The Index view must have the ViewModel for the partials to work, so not sure why it wont take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by passing the ViewModel to the view, and passing it to both partials:

```
@model App.Models.ViewModels.PersonViewModel

<h1>Manage People</h1>

@Html.Partial("_PersonEditForm", Model)
@Html.Partial("_PersonGrid", Model)
```

Then inside the partials, I specified the models within the viewmodel.  For example, in the form partial, the textbox helpers went from:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

To

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents since this has also been driving me crazy. What I have done is created separate viewmodels for each of the partial views. One similar to PersonEdit and one similar to PersonList.

So you end up with your main VM, and 2 smaller ones.

```
public class PersonIndexViewModel
{
    public PersonEditViewModel Person { get; set; }
    public List<PersonListViewModel> PeopleList { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEditViewModel
{
//    ...whatever info you want in your edit view
}

public class PersonListViewModel
{
//    ... whatever info you want in your table grid
}
```

Then you call it like so

```
@model App.Models.ViewModels.PersonViewModel

<h1>Manage People</h1>

@Html.Partial("_PersonEditForm", Model.Person)
@Html.Partial("_PersonGrid", Model.PeopleList)
```